# Custom Mapping tool for txt or excel

Tags: excel, etl

I have an excel dokument (tab delimitted). Every time before i can insert the excel in my program, i need to map the clients column names to the ones in my app.

So before i begin developing a mapping tool - it would be better if such already existed. But, i don't know i didn't find it.

This tool would actually read an excel or txt file, allow me to name all the names of the new columns on the right and drag and drop (for example).

Maybe this tool has an xml or something where i can define my custom columns, and then it would show op on the right side.

I hope you know what i mean and that someone also had the need for this.

Thanks

### info update

I wanted to mention a few things as an update to my question if it's not to late: I have about 50 headers/columns (example: First Name, Middle Name, Street1, Street2,..). So what i always need do every time a client gives me his excel file (contacts backup) is manually copy data for each of his column to the one on my side. And the problem is, every client has different column names, and also some of the columns of the client can go to multiple columns on my side.

So i think, if i can't find a solution, i would make a c++/qt app, which takes an excell and lets me to assign (dragdrop,etc..) every column of his side to on or more columns of my side.

I haven't done any vb programming, so if you can be a bit more detailed about how to aproach the solution i vb that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

**Firs part of answer**: You can achieve it with a simple vbscript. Copy this code in a vbs extension text file and double click.

```
Dim oCN As Connection
Dim fs As Scripting.FileSystemObject

Set oCN = New Connection
Set fs = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

sCSVFileName = "C:\Temp\Test1.csv"
sSourceSql = "SELECT field1 as f1, field2 as f2, ... FROM " & 
             fs.GetFileName(sCSVFileName )
sDestinationTable = "yourAppTable"

With oCN
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .Properties("Extended Properties").Value = 
          "TEXT;HDR=YES;FMT=TabDelimited;MAXSCANROWS=0"
    .Open fs.GetFile(sCSVFileName).ParentFolder
End With


sSql = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=" & 
       ServerName & ";Database=" & DBName & _
        IIf(IntegratedSecurity, ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;", _
            ";UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";") & _
        "]." & sDestinationTable & " " & sSourceSql

oCN.Execute sSql, , adExecuteNoRecords
```

More info at [microsoft social forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/afb454b2-e8d0-4997-95c6-45478425d8da/)

Also, you can parametrize mapping (source and destination tables and mapping fields) with a [external xml file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx).

**Second part of answer**: You ask if somebody else have this needed and if this is a good idea. Well, this is a very good proposal. And for this reason they are some solutions with this functionality.

First of all, this kind of technology is named [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load). Extract - Transform - Load.

Each database has its own tool

- [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)
- [Oracle data pump and loader](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/index-093639.html)
- etc.

Also exists specific technologies:

- [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) from microsoft.
- [IBM WebSphere DataStage](http://www.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/datastage/)
- etc.

All this tools have mapping columns capabilities.

Comment: @Johua, I have extend my answer to reply all your question. Excuse me to overlooked part of your question in first try.

Comment: Thanks danihp. First i will need to test a little bit before hitting awnser. I honestly haven't done any vb programming :(, the intetion was to do it in c++/qt. But it seems to make more sense in vb because i have an excel as input document. I will try your code snippet and read the rest of your awnser in detail first.

Comment: @johua, sorry, in answer I have read about tabdelimiter, I'm confused if you are talking about csv file or excel file. If your program is made with c++/qt it seems a good solution to develop your own field mapping screen, this keep application operating system independent (c++ + qt without VB).

Answer (score 1):

i use a generic mapping mechanism for that, configured by a couple arrays where you put the names used in your app (aDsNames) with these in your source, the csv file in your case (aDbNames)
I walk the fields in the source, check if the getDbName(name) is in aDsNames and if so write the value in the insertstring to the database.
You can do this both ways, usually my app requests a field to the databasemodule on the server, this module translates to the databasename and does the select.
Hope this is helpfull..
Cheers

```
select case store
  case "store1Midoc"
    aDbNames = array("id"    , "beheerder", "datumlijst", "rnr13" , "datvan", "dattot", "opmerking", "status" , "waarde", "kode"  , "type")
    aDsNames = array("id"    , "persnr   ", "datum     ", "rnr13" , "datvan", "dattot", "opmerking", "status" , "waarde", "kode"  , "type")
    aTypes   = array("number", "string",    "date"      , "string", "date"  , "date"  , "string"   , "number",  "number", "string", "string")
  case .....
end select

Function getDbName(dsName)
  Dim a
  getDbName = "undefined"
  If instr(join(aDsNames,","),dsName) Then
    For a = 0 to UBound(aDbNames)
      If aDsNames(a) = dsName Then 
        getDbName = aDbNames(a)
      End If
    Next 
  End If
End Function
```